# How do I get Mockito to mock a constant from another file?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

EDIT: The method I'm testing calls this constant that's defined in another class, so I want to test that th emethod works independently of how the other class defines the constant. Mocking it was the first thing I could think of, but I'm open to other ideas for how to test it in a clean, secure way

(Class, method, and variable names are genericized)

I'm trying to figure out how to write a test.
One of my methods gets a constant from another class, like so:

```
OtherClass.CONSTANT
```

and this constant is defined as:

```
public static final List<Long> CONSTANT =
  ImmutableList.of(1, 2);
```

In the test for this method, I want to mock this call. I've tried

```
when(OtherClass.CONSTANT).thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(1, 2));
```

but that gives me this error:

```
RegularImmutableList cannot be returned by otherFunction()
otherFunction() should return String
```

otherFunction() being some other function in the code base that doesn't seem to be related to anything I've been working on.

I've also tried

```
doReturn(ImmutableList.of(1, 2)).when(OtherClass.CONSTANT);
```

but, as you might be guessing, it gives me this error:

```
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

I'm pretty lost as to how exactly I should be mocking this constant.

Comment: What type is `OtherClass.CONSTANT`?

Comment: how is OtherClass.CONSTANT declared ? private ? final? static?

Comment: why do you want to mock a constant?

Comment: you can't mock static things with mockito (only), you need PowerMock(ito) ...https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116014/592355

Comment: A constant is a constant. You don't need to do anything to mock it: it's already defined. Mocks are only for when then thing you actually need to test it too hard to construct in tests.

Comment: The method I'm testing calls this constant that's defined in another class, so I want to test that it works independently of how the other class defines the constant. Mocking it was the first thing I could think of, but I'm open to other ideas for how to test it in a clean, secure way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't mock the value of a constant.

Likely the easiest method would be to convert your design to use an interface to supply the value, rather than using the value directly.

Something like:

```
interface ConstantSupplier {
    List<Long> get();
}

public MyClass(ConstantSupplier supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
}
```

Then you would replace references to the constant to `supplier.get()`.

This is now easy to mock:

```
ConstantSupplier supplier = mock(ConstantSupplier.class);
when(supplier.get()).thenReturn(List.of(4L, 9L));
```

Your non-mocked code could use a lambda to supply the real value:

```
obj = new MyClass(() -> OtherClass.CONSTANT);
```

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Thanks for the answer!